# What is the motivation for requiring "override" on an initialiser that has the same signature as one in a base?

Tags: swift

For methods it is clear to me that accidentally overriding a method could have bad consequences, so requiring developers to be explicit about it with the "override" keyword seems like a good idea.

However, as initialisers are invoked on a type (as it were) instead of on an object, I don't understand what overriding means in this context nor what kind of mistakes the requirement for the "override" keyword on initialisers is preventing.

Comment: I think it is for clarity so that you as a developer nows that you need to be extra careful when overriding an designatedinit with the exact same signature in a subclass since anyone using that init method in the subclass would expect the parameters to be sent to the superclass.  `Account.init(withStartingBalance amount: Double)` overriden by `SavingsAccount.init(withStartingBalance amount: Double)`, now where would you expect `amount` to go?

Comment: Can you give an example of such use in the subclass? The only use I can think of is in another initialiser, where either `super.init(...)` or `self.init(...)` is required.

Answer (score 0):

I find the `override` modifier to provide only a convenience and safety function of expressing the intent of a developer to either override an existing member of a class (when the modifier is present) or to introduce a new one (when the modifier is missing) so the compiler can perform the corresponding compile-time checks and inform the developer if the expressed intent could not be implemented (because there is nothing to override or because there is a signature collision with a member defined in one of the base classes).

You can argue that there is a difference between overriding a virtual member or providing a distinct statically dispatched initializer replicating the signature of an initializer of the base class. Technically, yes; but not semantically. Semantically you may still want to replicate the signature of an initializer of the base class, and the compiler is ready to perform the corresponding compile-time signature checks.

The Swift Language Guide in the chapter "Initialization" under the title [Initializer Inheritance and Overriding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID221) says:

> When you write a subclass initializer that matches a superclass designated initializer, you are effectively providing an override of that designated initializer. Therefore, you must write the `override` modifier before the subclass’s initializer definition. ...
>
> As with an overridden property, method or subscript, the presence of the `override` modifier prompts Swift to check that the superclass has a matching designated initializer to be overridden, and validates that the parameters for your overriding initializer have been specified as intended.

From this excerpt the role of the `override` modifier indeed appears to be small — to verify the intent of a developer to match a signature from the base class or not.